# Determine the values for a for which the matrix is diagonizable.

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

"Determine the values for a for which the matrix A is diagonizable. "

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}1&1\\a&1\end{bmatrix}$$

My first attempt solving this problem was to find the characteristic polynomial equation for lamda. Which got me to.. :

$$ λ = 1 ±\sqrt{(1)^2 +a}$$

Now my solution sheet states that the correct answer is for values $a > 0$

I have hard time understanding why that is that way. How do they know that it's exactly over $0$ There are obviously infinitely many numbers$$0<a$$ that would render two real eigenvalues.
 Would that not make it possible for the matrix to be diagonizable for those values? Why does it have to be $a>0$?

So what I was thinking was the answer was $a>-1$ Because if $a=1$ then there would only be one eigenvalue, which is $ λ=0$ and hence the matrix would be not diagonizable, because the eigenbasis that would be obtained from that particular eigenvalue would not span the space.

Comment: Could you insert steps to get to your values for $\lambda$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix is$$x^2-2x+1-a=(x-1)^2-a,$$which has real roots if and only if $a>0$; these roots are $1\pm\sqrt a$. So, in order that your matrix is diagonalizable over $\mathbb R$, it is necessary that $a>0$ indeed. Can you prove that it is also sufficient?

Comment: You are absolutely right. I somehow omitted that $1$. Naturally, the $a$ has to cancel it out for it to be possible to obtain real roots, thanks mr Santos!